# I can not select list item in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

What is the script for selenium in `li` tag. I used `Xpath` in selenium.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //*[@id='select2-product_cat-container']")).click() ;
```

But it is not working.

[image: This image is web code Sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id which is present on the html can be dynamic, so you can use the `text` in xpath to find the element.
You can click on it like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='Uncategorized']")).click();
```